# Superset running on docker not accessible

Tags: docker-compose, apache-superset

I am trying to run superset using docker-compose with the below command:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/superset.git
cd superset
git checkout 3.0.0
TAG=3.0.0 docker compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up -d
```

**The Port 8088 is open**, which I have checked with the telnet command and containers are also running fine

```
ONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                             PORTS                                       NAMES
f990ba77e656   apachesuperset.docker.scarf.sh/apache/superset:3.0.0   "/app/docker/docker-…"   3 hours ago   Up 59 seconds (health: starting)   8088/tcp                                    superset_worker
b5790fd47c8e   apachesuperset.docker.scarf.sh/apache/superset:3.0.0   "/app/docker/docker-…"   3 hours ago   Up 18 minutes (unhealthy)          0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp, :::8088->8088/tcp   superset_app
08b6c42b73c5   apachesuperset.docker.scarf.sh/apache/superset:3.0.0   "/app/docker/docker-…"   3 hours ago   Up 59 seconds                      8088/tcp                                    superset_worker_beat
77661662af68   postgres:14                                            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago   Up 18 minutes                      5432/tcp                                    superset_db
9596e814855f   redis:7                                                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago   Up 18 minutes                      6379/tcp                                    superset_cache
```

but when I tried with the browser for

> http://localhost:8088/

**nothing shown**. For curl, the result is same.

Can someone help here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Start docker compose in the foreground - without -d parameter - to see what might be going wrong and prevent the web server to start

Edit:

Just to be sure: did you run

```
TAG=3.0.0 docker compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml pull
```

first?